# SQL Server: replace multiple occurrences of a word with one

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I have a SQL Server table with a column `Event` which contains values like this:

```
[Event]
----------------------------------------
Payment stopped, Claim, Claim, Claim
Claim
Claim, Claim, Claim
Claim, Claim, Payment stopped, Case Closed
```

Now the user wants to view this column which has the summary count of the word 'Claim', so that the below column would look like

```
[Event]
-------------------------------------
Payment stopped, 3 Claims
Claim
3 Claims
2 Claims, Payment stopped, Case Closed
```

The word 'Claim' could present up to 400 times, they don't mind keeping the count in the starting of the value (3 Claims, Payment stopped), or end of the value (Payment stopped, 3 Claims). I have an udf that could get the count of this word, but removing the commas, spaces seems really difficult.

Is there a way to do this (with or without udf)? I am using SQL Server 2008.

Comment: This seems like a job for the frontent, not the db to me.Splitting apart a csv, reformatting it, and stitching it back together is going to be a PITA with SQL.

Comment: This is for a SSRS report. You think it could be possible with the options available in report designer?

Comment: Possibly, but what is possible is to design your tables properly so its not an issue. A column containing comma separated values which you need to manipulate is not the way to back a report. You should have an event table and a junction table leading back to your records.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to split the items by id using split function and get the count of each item. After that we need to conctenate the result. Below is the query with sample data.

```
declare @myevent table(id int identity,name varchar(max));

insert into @myevent select 'Payment stopped, Claim, Claim, Claim';
insert into @myevent select 'Claim';
insert into @myevent select 'Claim, Claim, Claim';
insert into @myevent select 'Claim, Claim, Payment stopped, Case Closed';

with cte as(
    select id,cast(count(item) over(partition by id,ltrim(rtrim(item))) as varchar(5)) + ' ' + ltrim(rtrim(item)) Item
    from @myevent
        cross apply dbo.Split(name,',')
)
,cte1 as(
    select distinct id,item
    from cte
)
select distinct id
        ,substring((select ','+item
                    from cte1 c1
                    where c1.id = c2.id
                    order by id
                    for xml path('')
                    )
                    , 2, 1000
                ) [result]
from cte1 c2
```

Below is the Split Function

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Split] (
      @InputString VARCHAR(8000),
      @Delimiter VARCHAR(50)
)

RETURNS @Items TABLE (
      Item VARCHAR(8000)
)

AS
BEGIN
      IF @Delimiter = ' '
      BEGIN
            SET @Delimiter = ','
            SET @InputString = REPLACE(@InputString, ' ', @Delimiter)
      END

      IF (@Delimiter IS NULL OR @Delimiter = '')
            SET @Delimiter = ','

      DECLARE @Item VARCHAR(8000)
      DECLARE @ItemList VARCHAR(8000)
      DECLARE @DelimIndex INT

      SET @ItemList = @InputString
      SET @DelimIndex = CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, @ItemList, 0)
      WHILE (@DelimIndex != 0)
      BEGIN
            SET @Item = SUBSTRING(@ItemList, 0, @DelimIndex)
            INSERT INTO @Items VALUES (@Item)

            -- Set @ItemList = @ItemList minus one less item
            SET @ItemList = SUBSTRING(@ItemList, @DelimIndex+1, LEN(@ItemList)-@DelimIndex)
            SET @DelimIndex = CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, @ItemList, 0)
      END -- End WHILE

      IF @Item IS NOT NULL -- At least one delimiter was encountered in @InputString
      BEGIN
            SET @Item = @ItemList
            INSERT INTO @Items VALUES (@Item)
      END

      -- No delimiters were encountered in @InputString, so just return @InputString
      ELSE INSERT INTO @Items VALUES (@InputString)

      RETURN

END -- End Function
```

## output

```
id  result
1   1 Payment stopped,3 Claim
2   1 Claim
3   3 Claim
4   1 Case Closed,1 Payment stopped,2 Claim,2 Claim
```

Comment: You should at least provide a link/provide more info on the split function

Comment: Thanks, but I only need the word count of 'Claim'.

Comment: Then put the where condition like where name='Claim'

Answer (score 1):

Try the below script

```
DECLARE @V_WORD NVARCHAR(10)    =   'Claim'

DECLARE @TABLE  TABLE
(   [Event] NVARCHAR(MAX))

INSERT INTO @TABLE
VALUES('Payment stopped, Claim, Claim, Claim'),('Claim'),('Claim, Claim, Claim'),('Claim, Claim, Payment stopped, Case Closed')

;WITH CTE
AS  (
        SELECT  [Event]
                ,CHARINDEX(@V_WORD,[Event],0)   [stpos]
                ,(LEN([Event]) - LEN(REPLACE([Event],@V_WORD,''))) / LEN(@V_WORD)   AS  [ECount]
        FROM    @TABLE
)

SELECT  REPLACE([Event]
                ,SUBSTRING([Event],[stpos],([ECount] * LEN(@V_WORD)) + (([ECount]-1) * 2))
                ,CAST([ECount] AS NVARCHAR) +' Claim' +
                    (CASE WHEN [ECount] > 1 THEN 's' ELSE '' END) 
                )   [Result]
FROM    CTE
```

Result:

```
Payment stopped, 3 Claims
1 Claim
3 Claims
2 Claims, Payment stopped, Case Closed
```

Comment: Thanks, This one works with the test data I have. Will test with the live data after a few hours.  In my data, the order won't change if there is more than one Claim available.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the other commenters that you should really look at your import processes and data schema to hold all the different events as individual table rows.

If this is not possible however, you can do the required manipulation relatively simply, without the use of `cte`s or additional functions.  Be mindful that this will not work for anything other than the word `Claim`, as that is all that has been asked for in your question:

```
declare @Event table(Event nvarchar(500));
insert into @Event values
 ('Payment stopped, Claim, Claim, Claim')
,('Claim')
,('Claim, Claim, Claim')
,('Claim, Claim, Payment stopped, Case Closed')
,('Payment stopped, Case Closed');

select Event
        ,case (len(Event) - len(replace(Event,'Claim','')))/5
                    when 0 then ''
                    when 1 then '1 Claim' + case when len(replace(Event,'Claim','')) > 0 then ', ' else '' end
                    else cast((len(Event) - len(replace(Event,'Claim','')))/5 as nvarchar(5)) + ' Claims' + case when len(replace(Event,'Claim','')) > 0 then ', ' else '' end
                 end
            + case when len(replace(Event,'Claim','')) > 0
                    then replace(replace(replace(Event,', Claim',''),'Claim, ',''),'Claim','')
                    else ''
                    end as Result
from @Event;
```

Output:

`````````````````````````````````````````````
Event                                       | Result
````````````````````````````````````````````|````````````````````````````````````````
Payment stopped, Claim, Claim, Claim        | 3 Claims, Payment stopped
Claim                                       | 1 Claim
Claim, Claim, Claim                         | 3 Claims, 
Claim, Claim, Payment stopped, Case Closed  | 2 Claims, Payment stopped, Case Closed
Payment stopped, Case Closed                | Payment stopped, Case Closed
`````````````````````````````````````````````

Comment: If the items order is changed the query fails. Ex: 'Claim, Payment stopped, Claim, Claim'. I am getting result as 3 Claims,  , Payment stopped

Comment: @Srinath  I am not getting the same error...  With your example of `Claim, Payment stopped, Claim, Claim` I am getting the correct result of `3 Claims, Payment stopped`

Comment: I have executed your query only, I am getting 3 Claims, , Payment stopped. Getting extra comma

Comment: @Srinath  I have just copied the code as is from this answer, added `Claim, ` to the start of the first values insert for `Claim, Payment stopped, Claim, Claim, Claim` and am getting `4 Claims, Payment stopped`.  I think you are perhaps not adding in the additional space at the end of the `Claim,`?

Comment: I have given space after the cliam ex: 'Claim , Payment stopped, Claim, Claim'.

Comment: @Srinath  That is still in the wrong format.  It should be 'Claim, Payment stopped, Claim, Claim'

Comment: Then it seems ok. appreciate your query

Comment: Brilliant!! This works fine,but I think instead of <<+ case when len(replace(Event,'Claim','')) > 0 then ', ' else '' end >> , I could say << + case when len(replace(replace(Event,', Claim',''),'Claim','')) > 0 then ', ' else '' end >> to remove the comma after the count when the event has only claims. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: I posted the simplified version of the requirement. Actually I have a table with 2 columns (Case_Id, event). A while back, the user wanted to group the events by case_id using a comma delimiter. Now they want to see the summary of the claim, Could please advise me if there is a better way available for this?

Comment: @Sarah  I do not know what you are asking for here, please update your question with additional details if you require a different solution.

Answer (score 0):

One more way is scalar function for doing this.

Schema from your Question.

```
CREATE TABLE #Event (EVENT_LIST VARCHAR(MAX))

INSERT INTO #Event
SELECT 'Payment stopped, Claim, Claim, Claim'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Claim'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Claim, Claim, Claim'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Claim, Claim, Payment stopped, Case Closed'
```

You need to do count of each word for every record. So need to create a Function which will execute per row once and gives result.

**Function with Logic:**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].FN_REPEAT_COUNT(@VAR VARCHAR(MAX))
RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN

 SET @VAR=@VAR+','
;WITH CTE AS  --Recursive CTE for calculating ',' indexes
(
    SELECT 1 INDX_FRM 
    , LEN(@VAR) LEN_VAR
    , CHARINDEX(',',@VAR)+1 AS INDX_TO

    UNION ALL

    SELECT CAST(INDX_TO+1 AS INT)
    , LEN_VAR
    , CHARINDEX(',',SUBSTRING(@VAR,INDX_TO+1,LEN_VAR))+INDX_TO+1 

    FROM CTE WHERE INDX_TO<LEN_VAR
)
,CTE2 AS(    --cte to generate records based on ',' index
SELECT  SUBSTRING(@VAR,INDX_FRM,INDX_TO-INDX_FRM-1 ) AS LIST FROM CTE
)
,CTE3 AS (  --cte for count of word Claim and making them back to column
SELECT (
        SELECT CAST(COUNT(CASE 
                        WHEN LIST = 'Claim'
                            THEN 1
                        ELSE NULL
                        END) AS VARCHAR(2)) + ' ' + LIST + ','
        FROM CTE2
        GROUP BY LIST
        FOR XML PATH('')
        ) COUNTED

)  
--Removing 0 and replacing ',' with Empty String
SELECT @VAR = REPLACE( SUBSTRING(COUNTED,1,LEN(COUNTED)-1),'0','') FROM CTE3
RETURN @VAR
END
```

And now just call the Scalar function on your column like below

```
SELECT *, dbo.FN_REPEAT_COUNT(EVENT_LIST) AS FN_RES FROM #Event
```

And the Output is

```
╔════════════════════════════════════════════╦═══════════════════════════════════════╗
║                 EVENT_LIST                 ║                FN_RES                 ║
╠════════════════════════════════════════════╬═══════════════════════════════════════╣
║ Payment stopped, Claim, Claim, Claim       ║ 3 Claim, Payment stopped              ║
║ Claim                                      ║ 1 Claim                               ║
║ Claim, Claim, Claim                        ║ 3 Claim                               ║
║ Claim, Claim, Payment stopped, Case Closed ║  Case Closed,2 Claim, Payment stopped ║
╚════════════════════════════════════════════╩═══════════════════════════════════════╝
```